# Pandas - Comparing and manipulating two dataframes under multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, associations, analysis, apriori

I am working on a project for university in which I want to use the associations analysis (apriori algorithm). As a data basis I am having two dataframes.

One is having the columns term, articleNumber and timestamp:

```
Clickstream
    term     articleNumber     timestamp
    queryC   2547              2018-09-27 18:26:58
    queryU   2157              2018-09-28 14:30:01
```

The other just term and timestamp:

```
Queries
    term                     timestamp
    queryA                   2018-09-27 18:26:47
    queryB                   2018-09-27 18:26:52
    queryC                   2018-09-27 18:26:58
    queryX                   2018-09-28 14:29:49
    queryP                   2018-09-28 14:30:00
    queryU                   2018-09-28 14:30:01
```

What I want to do is compare both data frames, therefore I take the term and the timestamp. If the difference between clickstream.timestamp - queries.timestamp is smaller then 10 seconds and the term is equal, I want to replace the term of the queries with the articleNumber of the clickstream. So that the Queries Dataframe looks like this:

```
Queries
        term                     timestamp
        queryA                   2018-09-27 18:26:47
        queryB                   2018-09-27 18:26:52
        2547                     2018-09-27 18:26:58
        queryX                   2018-09-28 14:29:49
        queryP                   2018-09-28 14:30:00
        2157                     2018-09-28 14:30:01
```

After that I want to iterate through the Queries dataframe from bottom to top and if the term before the current term is not a number and the difference between the current timestamp and the timestamp of the dataset before is smaller then 5 minutes, I want to put the terms together in one column of a new dataframe, so that the final result looks like this:

```
 Journey
    id     terms
    1      2547, queryB, queryA
    2      2157, queryP, queryX, queryC, queryB, queryA
```

Any tips on how to achieve this, are appreciated.

Comment: show step by stem how your dataframe output looks like, after 10 sec, conditions and 5min

Comment: I edited the post so that the steps are hopefully better to understand

Answer (score 1):

```
df_q=pd.DataFrame({
    'term':['queryC','queryU'],
    'articleNumber':[2547,2157],
    'timestamp':['2018-09-27 18:26:58','2018-09-28 14:30:01']
})
```

***task 1***

```
df_q.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df_q.timestamp)

df_c=pd.DataFrame({
    'term':['queryA','queryB','queryC','queryX','queryP','queryU'],
    'timestamp':['2018-09-27 18:26:47','2018-09-27 18:26:52','2018-09-27 18:26:58',
                 '2018-09-28 14:29:49','2018-09-28 14:30:00','2018-09-28 14:30:01']
})
df_c.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df_c.timestamp)

df_cq=pd.merge_asof(df_c,df_q,tolerance=pd.Timedelta("10s"),on='timestamp')
df_cq.loc[df_cq.term_y.notna(),'term_x']=df_cq.loc[df_cq.term_y.notna(),
                                                   'articleNumber']

task1_df =df_cq[['term_x','timestamp']]

print(task1_df)


   term_x           timestamp
0  queryA 2018-09-27 18:26:47
1  queryB 2018-09-27 18:26:52
2    2547 2018-09-27 18:26:58
3  queryX 2018-09-28 14:29:49
4  queryP 2018-09-28 14:30:00
5    2157 2018-09-28 14:30:01
```

***task 2***

```
df_test = df_cq.dropna()
df_all=pd.DataFrame()

for index,row  in df_test.iterrows():
    row=pd.DataFrame(row).transpose()
    rows = pd.merge_asof(df_cq,row,tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5m'),on='timestamp')
    rows.articleNumber_y = rows.articleNumber_y.bfill()
    rows=rows.dropna(subset=['articleNumber_y'])
    df_all = df_all.append(rows)

df_all.term_x_x=df_all.term_x_x.astype(str)

df_all = df_all[
    df_all.term_x_x.str.isalpha()
][['term_x_x','timestamp','articleNumber_y']]

    df_all=df_all.groupby('articleNumber_y').agg({'term_x_x':lambda x: ','.join(x)})

print(df_all)



                                    term_x_x
articleNumber_y                             
2157.0           queryA,queryB,queryX,queryP
2547.0                         queryA,queryB
```

for 2157 there is no `queryC` because it has been replaced as you want by `articleNumber`

Comment: I guess I have to experiment a little bit on the actual data basis to make it work, somehow it doesn´t yet. Thank you very much for this solution.

Comment: The last line before the print, should be indented to the left, right?